# What do i use to import datasets to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

so im a bit new and have been trying to build my own dataset. but what I've noticed is that TensorFlow imports it with google cloud. I don't have access to google cloud and was wondering how I would go about this. thank you

example:

```
path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('shakespeare.txt',
https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/shakespeare.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow takes the file wherever you specify.

You can find [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file) of  `tf.keras.utils.get_file()` function.

In the example you specified URL in Google Cloud Storage, that's why Tensorflow goes to GCS.

You can change it to a local path.